# My function does not work, how can i make it work?

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript, and I'm trying to make a system that:

1. Takes the user speed
2. Compares with the speed allowed on road
3. Asks the user if he was within speed or not

However, when I perform absolutely nothing happens. I have reviewed it thousands of times, looked for syntax errors and still does not run. Can you help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sist. De Multas</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>DETRAN</h1>
    
    
Velocidade de tráfego: <input type="number" name="txtvel" id="txtvel"> Km/h>

    <input type="button" value="Verificar" name="button">

    <div id="res">
        Resultado da verificação:
    </div>

    <script>
   
        function calcular(){
        var calcular = valor.addEventListener('click', calcular)
        var txtv = document.getElementById(txtvel)
        var conversor = Number(txtv.value)
        res.innerHTML = <p>`Sua Velocidade é de ${conversor}`</p>
            if(conversor > 60){
                res.innerHTML = <p>`Multa pendente no sitema por excesso de velocidade ${conversor}Km/h`</p>
            }else{
                res.innerHTML = 'Sem multa pendente'
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The immediate problem is that `var calcular = valor.addEventListener('click', calcular)` is _inside_ the `calcular` function.

Comment: Also, `document.getElementById(txtvel)` needs quotes around `txtvel`.

Comment: @Andy - that wouldn't cause an issue, since global `function calcular` isn't effected, and `var clacluar` is completely redundant as addEventListener returns `undefined` so it serves no purpose at all inside the function

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason the code doesn't run is because you never invoked the `calcular` function. You could run the function directly with `calcular()` or attach it as an event listener which is what I believe you are intending. To do this, you **must** move the `addEventListener` outside of the function before it will begin to work at all.

```js
function calcular() {
  //var calcular = valor.addEventListener('click', calcular)
  var txtv = document.getElementById(txtvel)
  var conversor = Number(txtv.value)
  res.innerHTML = <p>`Sua Velocidade é de ${conversor}`</p>
  if (conversor > 60) {
    res.innerHTML = <p>`Multa pendente no sitema por excesso de velocidade ${conversor}Km/h`</p>
  } else {
    res.innerHTML = 'Sem multa pendente'
  }
}
valor.addEventListener('click', calcular);
```

---

Based only on your code, this produces some errors which I will address shortly. Focusing on the eventListener line, we need to make sure it actually references the appropriate element. I'm not certain what `valor` is meant to be in your code, so I changed it to be `verificar` and apply `id="verificar"` to the `Verificar` button:

HTML

```html
<input type="button" value="Verificar" id="verificar" name="button">
```

JavaScript

```js
verificar.addEventListener('click', calcular);
```

---

The errors I was receiving when attempting to run the code were syntax errors regarding your `innerHTML` lines:

```js
res.innerHTML = <p>`Sua Velocidade é de ${conversor}`</p>
```

Which was easily fixable by placing the paragraph tags inside the template literal backticks:

```js
res.innerHTML = `<p>Sua Velocidade é de ${conversor}</p>`;
```

```js
function calcular() {
  //var calcular = valor.addEventListener('click', calcular)
  var txtv = document.getElementById(txtvel)
  var conversor = Number(txtv.value)
  res.innerHTML = `<p>Sua Velocidade é de ${conversor}</p>`;
  if (conversor > 60) {
    res.innerHTML = `<p>Multa pendente no sitema por excesso de velocidade ${conversor}Km/h</p>`;
  } else {
    res.innerHTML = '<p>Sem multa pendente</p>';
  }
}
```

---

At this point, it's nearly working. The following changes are needed to make it run as intended:

Refer to the text input as `txtvel`:

```js
// remove the `txtv` variable since we can refer directly to the element as `txtvel`
//var txtv = document.getElementById(txtvel);
var conversor = Number(txtvel.value);
```

Remove unnecessary `innerHTML` assignment:

```js
// This line is unnecessary because we overwrite it in the if..else blocks
//res.innerHTML = `<p>Sua Velocidade é de ${conversor}</p>`;
```

---

Full code:

```html
  <h1>DETRAN</h1>
  Velocidade de tráfego: <input type="number" name="txtvel" id="txtvel"> Km/h>
  <input type="button" value="Verificar" id="verificar" name="button">
  <div id="res">
    Resultado da verificação:
  </div>
  <script>
    function calcular() {
      //var calcular = valor.addEventListener('click', calcular);
      //var txtv = document.getElementById(txtvel);
      var conversor = Number(txtvel.value);
      //res.innerHTML = `<p>Sua Velocidade é de ${conversor}</p>`;
      if (conversor > 60) {
        res.innerHTML = `<p>Multa pendente no sitema por excesso de velocidade ${conversor}Km/h</p>`;
      } else {
        res.innerHTML = '<p>Sem multa pendente</p>';
      }
    }
    verificar.addEventListener('click', calcular);
  </script>
```